# Iterating over string to create array of Lat Long coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, gis

Elements of a list represent pairs of x and y decimal degree coordinates with a space between respective x and y coordinates formatted as strings:

`'34.894127 29.761515', '32.323574 30.166336', '32.677296 31.961439', '35.298668 31.559237', '34.894127 29.761515`

Thus far I can pick out the first element and set it as an x value:

`x = mystring[0:mystring.find(' ')]`

How can I iterate over this string to make an array consisting of pairs of x and y coordinates from this string?

Comment: Mitch's solution is fine, but if `tuple` is what you really wish, it'd be better:
`[tuple(map(float, coord.split())) for coord in string]`

Answer (score 3):

Where `mystring = mystring = "'34.894127 29.761515', '32.323574 30.166336', '32.677296 31.961439', '35.298668 31.559237', '34.894127 29.761515"` you could get a list of pairs like so:

```
x = [pair.lstrip().strip("'").split(' ') for pair in mystring.split(',')]
# gives: [['34.894127', '29.761515'], ['32.323574', '30.166336'], ['32.677296', '31.961439'], ['35.298668', '31.559237'], ['34.894127', '29.761515']]
```

or if you really want tuples:

```
x = tuple([tuple(pair.lstrip().strip("'").split(' ')) for pair in mystring.split(',')])
# gives: (('34.894127', '29.761515'), ('32.323574', '30.166336'), ('32.677296', '31.961439'), ('35.298668', '31.559237'), ('34.894127', '29.761515'))
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick method using `np.matrix` with string as input:

> If `data` is a string, it is interpreted as a matrix with commas    or
>   spaces separating columns, and semicolons separating rows.

```
string = ['34.894127 29.761515', '32.323574 30.166336', '32.677296 31.961439', 
          '35.298668 31.559237', '34.894127 29.761515']

np.matrix(';'.join(string))
#matrix([[ 34.894127,  29.761515],
#        [ 32.323574,  30.166336],
#        [ 32.677296,  31.961439],
#        [ 35.298668,  31.559237],
#        [ 34.894127,  29.761515]])

string = "'34.894127 29.761515', '32.323574 30.166336', '32.677296 31.961439', '35.298668 31.559237', '34.894127 29.761515"

np.matrix(string.replace(',', ';'))
#matrix([[ 34.894127,  29.761515],
#        [ 32.323574,  30.166336],
#        [ 32.677296,  31.961439],
#        [ 35.298668,  31.559237],
#        [ 34.894127,  29.761515]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split(',')` to get each string then `split()` to get the coordinates, for example using list-comprehension:

```
mystring =  "'34.894127 29.761515', '32.323574 30.166336', '32.677296 31.961439', '35.298668 31.559237', '34.894127 29.761515'"
coordinates = [tuple(map(float, x.replace("'", '').split())) for x in mystring.split(',')]
```

output:

```
[(34.894127, 29.761515), (32.323574, 30.166336), (32.677296, 31.961439), (35.298668, 31.559237), (34.894127, 29.761515)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a numpy array out of the list of strings:

```
import numpy as np

string = ['34.894127 29.761515', '32.323574 30.166336', '32.677296 31.961439', 
          '35.298668 31.559237', '34.894127 29.761515']

s  = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x.split(" "), string))).astype(float)
```

This results in  `s` being

```
[[ 34.894127  29.761515]
 [ 32.323574  30.166336]
 [ 32.677296  31.961439]
 [ 35.298668  31.559237]
 [ 34.894127  29.761515]]
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I needed! Thank you so much!